# Attempt to connect to Apache over different hosts

Tags: apache, server, router

I am currently running an Apache Server on my IP `192.168.8.77`. And I want to access it from lan having IP address `172.16.2.66`. I don't know much about the architecture of the network as you  might be seeing from my type of question. How should I go about ?

NOTE: I am able to access it from other network pc's connected over wifi because its connected over wifi but the other pcs are connected on lan.

Answer (score 0):

What is your gateway ?
You basically need a router which will do the bridge between the 2 subnets.

Comment: The gateway of the wifi one is 192.168.100.1 and that of lan is 172.16.1.1